# How do I get weapons to level X in singleplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I upgrade my weapons to level 10?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54473/how-can-i-upgrade-my-weapons-to-level-10)

In multiplayer, I have opened enough crates to get some of my weapons to level 10 (X). But in single player, I can only research upgrades through level 5 (V).

Can you get weapons to level X in singleplayer?

Additionally, is level V the max level for mods?

Comment: Fabian - I have added an additinoal question so that this is not a duplicate.

Comment: If you have an additional question, it's best asked separately so that it's easy to find for anyone who is wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only level up weapons to level X in a New Game+ in single player. V is the max level in your first playthrough.

Source: The official Prima strategy guide for ME3.