# Why can I only upgrade my guns to level VII?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was told [a new game plus allows you to upgrade your guns to level X](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54473/how-can-i-upgrade-my-weapons-to-level-10). But here I am stuck with guns maxed at VII (seven), which is a boost from V from the last playthrough, but I thought the new game + meant I get level X guns.

Why is my upgrade max level VII? I'm at the first part of a new game that lets you upgrade your weapons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this forum thread](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/347/index/10065112/1#10076660), you can only upgrade them to level 7 without "finding" them a second time.  When you pick them up again you get 3 extra levels, and you can upgrade through a terminal.  Collector's Edition and pre-order bonus weapons can only be upgraded at the terminal, whereas DLC weapons need to be picked up again just like main-game weapons.

As noted below, if you miss a gun you can't currently buy it again, so if you want to fully upgrade it without more than two playthroughs you better not miss any!

Comment: I wondered why I had to pick them up again...what happens if I don't pick up the gun on the mission, I have to buy it again? I also noticed I'm missing completely random gun mods

Comment: Annoying: You DON'T get to buy the guns, if you don't manually pick them up again you lose access to the last 3 levels until you play again I presume

Comment: @BenBrocka Too bad, thanks for following up though.